# Room DB runs on main thread when configured not to during instrumented test

Tags: android, junit, android-room, android-testing

I'm writing an instrumented test for an Android Room Database, but unfortunately it crashes due to the operation being done on the main thread: 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.` When configuring the test DB, I turned on the setting `allowMainThreadQueries()` to explicitly prevent this issue.

Sample code:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import java.io.IOException
import kotlin.test.assertTrue


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NewsDatabaseTest {

    private lateinit var cachedNewsDao: CachedNewsDao
    private lateinit var db: NewsDatabase

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, NewsDatabase::class.java)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        cachedNewsDao = db.cachedNewsDao()
    }

    @After
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDb() {
        db.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun ensure_dao_has_items() {

        val newsList: List<CachedNews> = cachedNewsDao.getNews()
        assertTrue { newsList.isEmpty() }
    }

}
```

The stacktrace initially points to the empty line in the only test method. And you can see the first line is the line which I explicitly turned off in `setUp`.

```
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:323)
    at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
    at com.package.feature.news.cache.CachedNewsDao_Impl.getNews(CachedNewsDao_Impl.java:97)
    at com.package.feature.news.cache.NewsDatabaseTest.ensure_dao_has_items(NewsDatabaseTest.kt:44)
```

Why is Room ignoring the allow main thread query config?

I found a workaround to run tests via command line: `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`.